# Pydantic: dataclass vs BaseModel

Tags: python, pydantic

What are the advantages and disadvantages of using Pydantic's dataclass vs BaseModel? Are there any performance issues or is it easier to Pydantic's dataclass in the other python module?

Comment: I've implemented the validation of pure dataclasses: https://github.com/EvgeniyBurdin/validated_dc

Comment: i must say that the `dataclass` is a far simpler (more convenient) structure than pydantic version (probably for bigger projects). . . https://youtube.com/live/0lCIkY32AdI?feature=share

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Your question is answered in Pydantic's [documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/dataclasses/), specifically:

> Keep in mind that `pydantic.dataclasses.dataclass` is a drop-in replacement for `dataclasses.dataclass` with validation, **not** a replacement for `pydantic.BaseModel` (with a small difference in how initialization hooks work). There are cases where subclassing `pydantic.BaseModel` is the better choice.
>
> For more information and discussion see [samuelcolvin/pydantic#710](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/710).

The discussion link will give you some of the context you are looking for. In general, Pydantic's `BaseModel` implementation is not bound to behave the same as Python's `dataclass` implementation. The example cited in the issue above is one good example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List

@dataclass
class A:
    x: List[int] = []

# Above definition with a default of `[]` will result in:
#   ValueError: mutable default <class 'list'> for field x is not allowed: use default_factory
# If you resolve this, the output will read as in the comments below.

class B(BaseModel):
    x: List[int] = []

print(A(x=[1, 2]), A(x=[3, 4])) # Output: A(x=[1, 2]) A(x=[3, 4])
print(B(x=[1, 2]), B(x=[3, 4])) # Output: x=[1, 2] x=[3, 4]
```

If what you want first and foremost is `dataclass` behavior and then to simply augment it with some Pydantic validation features, the `pydantic.dataclasses.dataclass` approach may be what you want. Otherwise, `BaseModel` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 11):

The `__repr__` string representation function for BaseModel is different from that of dataclass:

```py
@dataclass()
class Foo:
    number: int

class Bar(BaseModel):
    number: int

f = Foo(number = 1.4)
b = Bar(number = 1.4)

print(f)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
Foo(number=1.4)
number=1
```

Comment: The `__repr__` is the same, but `__str__` is different. 

I can't post code blocks in comments, but try `print(repr(f))`.
`print(f) == print(str(f))`

Comment: @Phil997 Why are you initializing with incompatible types (`float` vs `int`) when you are actually trying to demonstrate the difference in the automatic conversion to `str`? By the way, you can (and should) correct all the issues mentioned. Please use the [**Edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65288785/edit) function, it is there for this very purpose. Thank you!